# ImportError: No module named 'shell' when importing twill

Tags: python, twill

i was trying to import from twill module but this error happens to  me what should i do ?

```
from twill.commands import *
go("http://www.python.org/")
```

this is the error :

```
  File "d:\Users\Erfan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twill-0.9-py3.5.egg\twill\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from shell import TwillCommandLoop

ImportError: No module named 'shell'
```

Comment: Can you check if you have shell.py available in your site-packages ? Here's a reference to shell.py available within twill. https://github.com/ctb/twill/blob/master/twill/shell.py

Comment: @worker_bee it was there ... didn't change anything

Comment: Did you use easy_install or "pip install" for installing twill?

Comment: @worker_bee installed it using pip install

Comment: You are using python3.5, are you absolutely sure it would work for python3.5 - I see the README is quite outdated. You are better off trying to use python 2.7 for it then.

Comment: @worker_bee Thanks i would try that

Comment: @worker_bee btw what can i use instead of that ?